# Routing for Angular with common layout for some feature modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an Angular 7 app with 3 user roles, A, B & C. A & B share the same visual layout but the menu items change (theme and structure are the same, data is different). C has a completely different layout.

My application has `AppModule`, `SharedModule`, `CoreModule`, `HomeModule`, `AModule`, `BModule` & `CModule`. My common layout lives in a component called `CommonLayoutComponent` which is exported from `SharedModule` and it is used in Modules A and B.

The workflow: the user lands on a home page that has three button, which will route to modules, A, B and C. Or she might navigate directly to the right module by bookmarking the relevant URL.

My app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
  { path: 'c', component: CComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Questions:

1. Should I still bootstrap `AppComponent` in my AppModule even though I am not doing anything in this component except having `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the app.component.html ?
2. How can I treat my `CommonLayoutComponent` as a master/layout page (like ASP.NET MVC layout page) and pop my `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside it for modules A and B?

Comment: So, you want to bootstrap `CommonLayoutComponent ` instead of `AppComponent ` ?

Comment: @selemmn I don't know, I mean, maybe HomeComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to keep same layout for A and B, make them child routes and put layout related html + an additional router-outlet inside CommonLayoutComponent component. Something like this..

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: CommonLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
            { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'c', component: CComponent }
];
```

Comment: That answers my second question, what about the first question?

Comment: You must at-least have one component for bootstrapping. And the root level router-outlet shall be placed inside it. So yes you'll still need it. Otherwise where will you render /home or /c routes?